# cuML Random Forest- Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I save the trained model

Tags: python, pickle, random-forest, coredump, rapids

I am trying to save my Rf model after training it and I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I have tried to save it before training and it does not give me any problem with pickle.
I have tried with other [cuML](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/api.html#random-forest) algorithms, and it has let me save them after training.

```
from cuml.ensemble  import  RandomForestClassifier as rf_cuML
import pickle

model = rf_cuML(random_state=0)
output = open('model.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(model, output) #This saving works

model.fit(train_features, train_labels)
output = open('model_trained.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(model, output) #This saving does not work
```

This line throws the following error:
`pickle.dump(model, output) #This saving does not work` -->
**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

System specifications:

1. Ubuntu 18.04
2. RAM 32GB
3. NVIDIA-SMI 495.29.05 Driver Version: 495.29.05 CUDA Version: 11.5[Cuda info][1]
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8reIM.png
4. Rapids 22.04
5. Python 3.9
6. CPU: Intel Core i7-7700
7. GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER 8 GB
8. pickle 4.0

Comment: 3.Cuda info:   
  NVIDIA-SMI 495.29.05 
  Driver Version: 495.29.05
  CUDA Version: 11.5

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

After some research, I updated the **rapids version to 22.06** and it now **allows** me to **save** the trained Random Forest model with pickle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).